# Tableview reload row after come back tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to reload row after come back to tableview.

In first reload tableview I can reload row with below code and data effected.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

When I come to previous view with back button and then open same tableview again I can not reload row.

Code is working I can see when reload code calls cellForRowAt indexPath function but data not effect it.

Any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do same code in viewWillAppear function. Something like

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
```

But you need to pass back information about what indexPath was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
it will definitely work.

`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;`